# Fortran Derived Type - Public Pointer to a Private Array

Tags: pointers, fortran, derived-types

I'm trying to define a Fortran derived type that has a private allocatable array. However, I would like to be able to access the array via a public pointer for use in other modules. E.g.

```
type,public :: test
private
 real,allocatable :: a(:,:,:)
contains
 real,pointer,dimension(:,:,:),public :: point => a
end type test
```

I just get a compiler error when attempting it like the above.

Is this possible without writing a subroutine that does the pointing for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The syntax error is perhaps because you have the pointer component in the type bound procedure part of the type definition (after the contains), not in the component part (before the contains).

Beyond syntax, there are some problems with what you want to do:

- You cannot associate a pointer with a component of a type definition.  Pointers can be associated with components of objects (a subobject).  Similarly, you cannot associate a pointer with something that doesn't have the target attribute.  Types and components of types can't have the target attribute.  Variables of that type, or objects pointed at by pointer components of an object may have the target attribute.
- You cannot associate a pointer with something that isn't allocated.  If something isn't allocated then there isn't anything to point at.
- An initializer for a pointer component cannot refer to something that is allocatable.  In addition to the target attribute the thing that it refers to must have the SAVE attribute.  As the case with the TARGET attribute, variables have the save attribute, not type or component definitions.
- Associating a pointer with a component of an object may defeat the point of making the component private in the first place.  This leads to the question - what are you trying to do?

Comment: A comprehensive answer, thank you. I have some Fortran code that uses the derived type array as private and has a 'point' function associated with the type that pointed to the private array. However I'm trying to utilise OpenACC directives in other parts of the program and they don't work with a pointer subroutine,  so I was trying to find a work around. I will try to leave the pointer as null and point it after the array has been allocated, thank you again for your answer!

Comment: You can set it to point in the right place in the type's constructor.

Comment: For clarity... structure constructors in Fortran look like functions (in the absence of any type parameter specifications).  User provided "constructors" that follow that pattern and are implemented as functions (perhaps hiding the real structure constructor) can't practically be used to pointer associate one component with another component - the pointer gets associated with something that will cease to exist shortly after the function returns.  You must construct using a subroutine.  Be mindful of the myriad of ways that the association status of a pointer may subsequently become undefined.